# Please tell me what's wrong with this code

Tags: c, loops, infinite-loop, do-while

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int i=1,s=0;
    do{
        s+=i;
    }while(i<=10);
    printf("sum is %d",s);
}
```

this code is not giving any output, please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: it's an endless loop because i never changes

Comment: you don't increment ```i```

Comment: thanks, now I know I have not incremented the value of `i`

Comment: `s+=i++` should fix it for you.

Comment: Use a for loop instead, then the syntax comes naturally.

Answer (score 2):

You have an infinite loop because the variable `i` that is used in the condition of the do-while loop is not being changed within the loop. It stays equal to 1 as it was initialized.

```
do{
    s+=i;
}while(i<=10);
```

It seems you mean

```
do{
    s += i++;
} while( i <= 10 );
```

or

```
do{
    s += i;
} while( ++i <= 10 );
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Also it is desirable to flush the output buffer by including the new line character `'\n'` in the output stream like

```
printf( "sum is %d\n", s );
```

Answer (score 1):

you didn't increment i;

```
do
{
   s+=i;
   i++;
}while(i<=10);
```